# OPENCV - Filter an image directly with pointer acces and filter with kernel matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm reading the book OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook. I've executed two function "sharpen" and "sharpen2D" and the result is the same if the processed image is gray-scale but is different if the image is color. In particular the result seems right also in color case for the "sharpen2D" function and incomprehensible for the "sharpen" function. Why? The result should be exactly the same or am I wrong?

```
using namespace cv;

void sharpen(const Mat &image, Mat &result) {
// allocate if necessary
result.create(image.size(), image.type());
for (int j= 1; j<image.rows-1; j++) { // for all rows
    // (except first and last)
    const uchar* previous = image.ptr<const uchar>(j-1); // previous row
    const uchar* current = image.ptr<const uchar>(j);
    // current row
    const uchar* next = image.ptr<const uchar>(j+1); // next row
    uchar* output= result.ptr<uchar>(j); // output row
    for (int i=1; i<image.cols-1; i++) {
        *output++= saturate_cast<uchar>(
        5*current[i]-current[i-1]   
        -current[i+1]-previous[i]-next[i]);
    }
}
// Set the unprocess pixels to 0
result.row(0).setTo(Scalar(0));
result.row(result.rows-1).setTo(Scalar(0));
result.col(0).setTo(Scalar(0));
result.col(result.cols-1).setTo(Scalar(0));
}

void sharpen2D(const Mat &image, Mat &result) {
//kernel=matrice convoluta con l'immagine, stesso effetto della sharpen
// Construct kernel (all entries initialized to 0)
Mat kernel(3,3,CV_32F,Scalar(0));
// assigns kernel values
kernel.at<float>(1,1)= 5.0;
kernel.at<float>(0,1)= -1.0;
kernel.at<float>(2,1)= -1.0;
kernel.at<float>(1,0)= -1.0;
kernel.at<float>(1,2)= -1.0;
//filter the image
filter2D(image,result,image.depth(),kernel);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
Mat image, result, result2;

image = imread("a.jpg");

cvtColor( image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY );

namedWindow( "Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
namedWindow( "Result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
namedWindow( "Result2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

sharpen(image,result);

sharpen2D(image,result2);

imshow("Image",image);  

imshow("Result",result);
imshow("Result2",result2);

waitKey(0); 

return 0;
}
```

Thanks to the reply I understood my mistake and I've modified my sharpen function but the image result is completely black, where I'm wrong?

```
void sharpen(const Mat &image, Mat &result) {
// allocate if necessary
result.create(image.size(), image.type());
if (image.channels()==1){
    for (int j= 1; j<image.rows-1; j++) { // for all rows
        // (except first and last)
        const uchar* previous = image.ptr<const uchar>(j-1); // previous row
        const uchar* current = image.ptr<const uchar>(j);
        // current row
        const uchar* next = image.ptr<const uchar>(j+1); // next row
        uchar* output= result.ptr<uchar>(j); // output row
        for (int i=1; i<image.cols-1; i++) {
            *output++= saturate_cast<uchar>(
            5*current[i]-current[i-1
            -current[i+1]-previous[i]-next[i]);
        }
    }
    // Set the unprocess pixels to 0
    result.row(0).setTo(Scalar(0));
    result.row(result.rows-1).setTo(Scalar(0));
    result.col(0).setTo(Scalar(0));
    result.col(result.cols-1).setTo(Scalar(0));
}
if (image.channels()==3)//color image
{
    vector<Mat> planes;
    vector<Mat> planes2;
    Mat image1,temp;
    split(image,planes);        

    for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
    {
        image1.create(planes[k].size(), planes[k].type());
        for (int j= 1; j<planes[k].rows-1; j++) 
        { 
            // for all rows
            // (except first and last)
            const uchar* previous = planes[k].ptr<const uchar>(j-1); 
            const uchar* current = planes[k].ptr<const uchar>(j);
            const uchar* next = planes[k].ptr<const uchar>(j+1);
            uchar* output= image1.ptr<uchar>(j); // output row

            for (int i=1; i<planes[k].cols-1; i++) 
            {
                    *output= saturate_cast<uchar>(
                    5*current[i]-current[i-1]   
                    -current[i+1]-previous[i]-next[i]);
            }
        }
        image1.row(0).setTo(Scalar(0));
        image1.row(image1.rows-1).setTo(Scalar(0));
        image1.col(0).setTo(Scalar(0));
        image1.col(image1.cols-1).setTo(Scalar(0));
        planes[k]=image1;
    }
    merge(planes,result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like you are handling different depths in your sharpen function, so, that is probably an expected result. You might want to read up on how OpenCV stores an [image](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html?highlight=accessing%20element) in memory.

Comment: Oh god yes, in color case I have to do the sharpen opeartion for all the 3 channels.